# If $G$ is abelian and $\varphi:G\to H$ is a non-trivial homomorphism, then does $H$ have to be Abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-actions, group-homomorphism

If $G$ is abelian and $\varphi:G\to H$ is a non-trivial homomorphism, then does $H$ have to be Abelian?

My guess is yes since
if $a,b\in G$ and $\varphi (a*b)=\varphi(a)*\varphi(b)$ and $\varphi(b*a)=\varphi(a*b)$ then $\varphi(a)*\varphi(b)=\varphi(b)*\varphi(a)$,
so $H$ must be abelian too.

Is this sound reasoning?

Comment: The *image* is an abelian subgroup of $H$, but $H$ itself does not have to be abelian if the homomorphism is not surjective. Just map $G$ to $G\times S_3$ to see the "target group" can be nonabelian.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $G=\Bbb Z_2$ and $H=\Bbb Z_2\times S_3$. Define

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: G&\to H,\\
g&\mapsto (g,e).
\end{align}$$

Then $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, $G$ is abelian, but $H$ is nonabelian.

> **Exercise:** Generalise $\varphi$, $G$, and $H$ to find other counterexamples.

> Hint: Let $\varphi:G\to H$ be a homomorphism that is not surjective. Then ${\rm Im}(\varphi)$ is indeed abelian if $G$ is abelian. What can you say about $(H\setminus {\rm Im}(\varphi))\cup\{e\}$?